# Facebook Authentication .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm fairly new to web development so I've been experimenting with the template code Microsoft has provided through their default .NET Core Application option. I was able to successfully deploy the website using Azure services and connected it to a server with its own database.

One of the things I've been struggling with, however, is setting up Facebook authentication. I followed this guide: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-using-facebook-in-asp-net-core-2-0/
and was able to successfully login with Facebook locally, but when I try to publish and go to the website with the new code in ConfigureServices function I get a HTTP 500 error.

My website is: vincecoreapp.azurewebsites.net

Here is the snippet that I inserted:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
            {
                facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
            });


            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

Any advice would be extremely helpful, thank you!

Comment: A 500 error is meaningless. You need to get the actual exception that's being raised, including the stacktrace. Use logging or, if this site isn't already live, you can temporarily set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to "Development", to allow the developer exception page to show.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you haven't added the published "something.azurewebsites.net" URL to the Valid OAuth Redirect Settings in your [Facebook App Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhgjO.png)

Comment: The problem is that I can't even access my website when I include that snippet of code. When I remove it, everything is deployed perfectly fine so I don't know why it's causing the HTTP 500 error. The website link is vincecoreapp.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: Ah, in that case I would guess that it's missing something that that code needs like the configuration values or the DLL that defines the AddFacebook() method. The best way to find out would be to enable logging to get the actual error. You could do as Chris suggested in the comment above or try using the logstream at https://vincecoreapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream. The logstream is best fetched with CURL but I've found that it tends to work in browsers at least most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

namespace VinceCoreApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
        {
            facebookOptions.AppId = "680347028977338";
            //Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
            facebookOptions.AppSecret = "fc943b8782d7d5d83a4446709f2d903a";
            //Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
        });


        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

}

This solved the problem